# sudo cp command to copy into launchDaemons

Tags: applescript

Just simplyfing a process for some internal mac users to put files in the right places but having trouble with a plist file needing to go in /Library/LaunchDaemons. Using some applescript to accomplish this. Unfortunately (for me) LaunchDaemons is read only, so need to sudo root privilege to copy a file into there. I can't seem to get it right as to how to do that with applescript. Copying files to unrestricted locations is done just fine with something like

```
do shell script ("/bin/cp " & posix_path & "file_to_copy.crt" & "/path/to/folder/")
```

For the plist file in LaunchDaemons, ideally something like below would work,

```
do shell script ("sudo /bin/cp " & posix_path & "file_to_copy.plist" & "/Library/LaunchDaemons/") with administrator privileges
```

I've tried a lot of variations but no luck. Reading through stack overflow I haven't spotted a question quite like this. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As far as using `sudo` in a **do shell script** *command*, do not use `sudo` in a **do shell script** *command*, have a look at: [Technical Note TN2065 do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html)

As far as `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`, it is not read-only! In macOS Big Sur, here are the permissions on a recent 11.4 build:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 root wheel - 96 May 30 13:01 LaunchDaemons
```

Note that it is writable for `root` and why you need to use `with administrator privileges` when using the `do shell script` *command* to write to it.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*

```
do shell script "cp '/path/to/filename.plist' '/Library/LaunchDaemons/'" with administrator privileges
```

The above `do shell script` *command* works for just fine me.

Note the *single-quotes* around the **POSIX paths**.

If you are not using hard coded **POSIX paths** and using *variables* and concatenating the `do shell script` *command*, you can use e.g, `the quoted form of theFilename` or `theFilename's quoted form`, etc.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*

```
set theFilename to the POSIX path of (choose file)
set theDestinationFolder to "/Library/LaunchDaemons/"

do shell script "cp " & ¬
    theFilename's quoted form & space & ¬
    theDestinationFolder's quoted form ¬
    with administrator privileges
```